# How to speed up reindexing process

Tags: magento-1.7, indexing, magento-community, magento-1.8

I'm testing a Magento store (CE 1.7.2) with 180k fake products. A big problem is the reindex time process (reindex all), 2-3hrs. (2hrs with Magento CE 1.8).
Has anyone any suggestions about how to speed up the whole process?
Thanks

Comment: Ditto @FabianBlechschmidt here on duplicity… but want to point out that the big thing here is *improper hardware*. I've got a setup with 5 Millions SKUs on Magento where a full re-index takes roughly 4 hrs to run. It is running EE 1.13, but the fact remains that the bottleneck is in the capacity of the database server to deal with the queries, and not Magento itself.

Comment: For furture reference, the above comment is not relevant, EE 1.13 has delta indexing so it is not comparable in any way to CE. For CE, once you get to 10s-100s thousands of products you have serious performance issues, hosting is the solution and should be 1% of revenue from a top-tier provider, preferably scalable for mass updates/indexing and offloading these processes to an admin server (this is the setup we use).

Comment: Thank You all, and I apologize if I asked a question that had already been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing is core mechanism of Magento which helps to store working properly and fast (flat tables). It is difficult to manage and process so many products(180K) really. And it is really difficult job to implement some solution for indexing process on code level. You should optimize and tune your hardware(memory, processor) and software(MySql, php caches). Here is given great optimizing and performance tricks and try to follow them:
[How to optimise database architecture for high volume sites?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-to-optimise-database-architecture-for-high-volume-sites/361)
[Which MySQL Server provides a better performance for Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/936/which-mysql-server-provides-a-better-performance-for-magento/941)
[What is the Best Magento Server Setup?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/460/what-is-the-best-magento-server-setup/466)
[Magento page loading taking too much time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/602/magento-takes-too-much-time-to-load-it-pages)